# Maximum performance for node HTTP server?

Tags: node.js, performance, http, network-programming, server

I'm running a test trying to draw maximum delivery speed from a Node HTTP server. It's a simple server.
In my test I have 50K virtual clients establishing a permanent connection with the server (I run ulimit -n 99999 before). Then, upon another event, an HTTP connection to a different port, the server sends one message to each virtual client. At the end all clients receive the corresponding message.
Sending all messages takes minutes in my tests. Are there any recommendations that would help me improve these measurements so that I can send 50K messages in seconds instead of minutes?
The server is running in a m1.medium AWS instance. The idea is to improve performance with the same platform.

Copying the server code:

```
var http = require("http");
var connectionResponse = [];
var connectionIndex = 0;

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log("Received connection " + connectionIndex);
  response.setTimeout(1200000, function() {
    console.log("Socket timeout");
  });
  connectionResponse[connectionIndex] = response;
  connectionIndex++;

}).listen(8888);

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log("8887 connected - Will respond");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Triggered all responses");
  response.end();

  console.log("Begin notifications:" + new Date().toISOString());

  for(var i = 0; i < connectionIndex; i++) {
    connectionResponse[i].writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain", "Content-Length": 4, "transfer-encoding" : ""});
    connectionResponse[i].write("CAFE");
    connectionResponse[i].end();
  }
  console.log("End notifications" + new Date().toISOString());

}).listen(8887);
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting this http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets to a sufficient number

```
var http = require('http');
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = xxx;
var https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = xxx;
```

Using nodejs clustering module, http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Now, regarding the clustering, it really depends on what you want to do. The default example can go long way before you have to tweak it. An example would be

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case its a HTTP server
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
  }).listen(8000);
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you. I already have 50K sockets connected. Maybe clustering could help me since m1.medium instances have 2 vcpu's. Maybe I can reduce time by half.

Comment: I've added some code as per @Ben's comment. Regarding the clustering, you'll have to adapt to your specific case. What's more interesting that the connected sockets (if you are doing long-polling this does not apply) is requests per second. Have you counted that ?

Comment: @oglu Can you add some code for cluster? maxSockets is not a problem at this moment. I cna have 50K connected sockets. Thanks.

Comment: @rodolk The max sockets are not about the connected sockets TO nodejs but FROM nodejs. That is, if you have a backend service, with the default settings, you can only have 5 concurrent http requests which is quite limiting (that's why I told you that reqs/sec is a better metric). Now, for the cluster thing, I'll provide you with a simple example for HTTP

Comment: @oglu, thank you for the explanation. In my case I'm having 50K concurrent requests, the server receives the request and stores the response object in an array as shown in my code. At some point I have 50K concurrent requests waiting for the response. Then when a request arrives on port 8887, the server sends back the 50K responses. Maybe I'm not understanding the difference?

Comment: Imagine you have your nodejs server (called A) and an external service (called B). Your server accepts x connections that need this external service. What is gonna happen is the following. In the A->B communication you can have only 5 concurrent requests. That is, A will continue to accept requests  but it will keep them "inactive" until it can process them through B.  That effectively mean that no matter how many connections your server can ACCEPT it can actually PROCESS a small fraction of them.